# Stellar-core multiple instances

Tags: stellar-core, horizon

I am planning on running 3 stellar core instances for high availability purposes.

My question is, do I need to have separate db for each core instance? Same for buckets as well, I am assuming buckets can't be shared and has to be separate for each instance.

Similar question on horizon as well, if I want to run 3 instances, do I need to have 3 separate databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. For high availability, each instances should be fully independent of the others.

Comment: Thanks. What about horizon? can I run 1 ingest node with multiple non ingest nodes? this makes having only 1 db for horizon and I will have to accept the risk of either the ingest node or db going down

Comment: Yes, you can run one ingest node with multiple non-ingest nodes. But only one ingest node per-database.

Answer (score 0):

Every core instance needs its own dedicated db instance
Horizon instances can share db instance, but only one instance has to be configured to ingest